# Factory pattern with Unity Buildup<T> trouble

Tags: c#, unity-container, inject

My demo code is very simple

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System;

public interface IDecorator
{
    string GetA();
}

public class Decorations:IDecorator
{

    public string GetA()
    {
        return "temp";
    }
}

public class Base
{

}

public class Derive : Base
{
    [Dependency]
    public IDecorator DerivedDecorations { get; set; }
}


public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Base bd = new Derive(); // here is the point

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IDecorator, Decorations>();

        container.BuildUp(bd); // bd.DerivedDecorations is null

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The `DerivedDecorations` in Derive class could not be resolved on above case

if we change the code to `Derive bd = new Derive();` there is no issue

I am not clear about the reason, because we are using factory pattern, could any one give me some reason of that ?

Comment: why don't you just do `Derive temp = new Derive(); container.BuildUp(temp );  Derive bd = temp; `

Comment: because we use factory.... the code is something like Base b = GetDerived()....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the generic [BuildUp-Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee651459.aspx) overload.

Unity uses the specified Type of T to examine it´s properties and determine dependencies to be injected.

In your case, you are not explicitly specifying T but rather rely on [type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881824/type-inference-in-c-sharp), which resolve to class "Base" (as the parameters variable type is of type "Base").

So either declare your variable accordingly, or try another approach via the [non-generic version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650691.aspx):

```
container.BuildUp(typeof(Derived), bd);
```

or

```
container.BuildUp(bd.GetType(), bd); //which resolves to "Derived"
```

which in the given example makes currently little sense, but I expect your sample to be broken down for simplicity.

Comment: another hint: maybe it would be possible to not "buildUp" an existing instance, but rather let the factory create an instance via container, in which case the full-type is known.
This would infer that "Derived" needed to be registered in the container, also.